# Trying to show the difference of data after refreshing by creating an archive of query

Tags: powerbi

Currently i have sales information broke down by region and country and sales person. After every refresh, i would like to understand what has changed (i.e. sales person has received more of less revenue after new data is added.

So what I did was to duplicate another query as an archive and store a old file of old information.
For the visuals I will subtract the new data with old data.

Measure 2 independently [image]

Measure 1 independently[image]

I'm using date table as column, region, country and salesperson as rows in the visualisation.
For updated information I created a measure for the values  :

```
MEASURE 1 = 
VAR __PREV_MONTH = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales'[revenue]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUM('Sales'[salesperson]) - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH)
```

Likewise, I created a new table to archive old information and created a measure as such :

```
MEASURE 2 = 
VAR __PREV_MONTH = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales Archive'[Sales]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))
RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUM('Sales Archive'[Salesperson]) - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH)
```

[image]

Lastly to get a table showing the difference between the two measures I created another measure stating

```
Check Difference = if(Measure 1 = Measure 2, " -", 'Measure 1' - 'Measure 2')
```

When I do this, i get duplicated column of dates with no changes but there is values in total only
[image]

Comment: `__PREV_MONTH` is last year? What columns do you have in your Matrix `Columns well`? If a measure returns a value it will be displayed regardless of context and your diff measure (which looks incorrect) is doing just that.

Comment: Hi Sam, no it should have been labelled as __MonthPreviousYear. I am looking at the same month but compared to last year. In the columns of matrix I have the date table (which has a relationship to the archive and sales table) one to many relationship

Comment: Ok, does Measure 1 and Measure 2 version of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aos3W.png look good? Can you share what these two look like independently.

Comment: That is measure 1 independently. Measure 2 I attached again in the question. Both look good independently. when i put both together I run into the first image

Comment: After trying out it was due to the relationship of the table. As a quick fix i have removed the if statement for check difference and put as Measure 1- Measure 2.